# Gnu screen with local scrollback buffer?

Tags: linux, ssh, remote, gnu-screen

I'm using a remote server over a very slow and unreliable network connection.

So, I want to use gnu screen in order not to lose what I'm doing whenever I get disconnected.

But I want a local scrollback buffer, on my local computer, so that scrollback doesn't have to go across the network, which is incredibly slow.

Is there either something like gnu screen, but with a local scrollback buffer; or else a way of using gnu screen with a local scrollback buffer?

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46483/how-to-allow-page-up-in-gnu-screen

Answer (score 7):

Found part of the answer, from http://aperiodic.net/screen/faq: put the following into the `.screenrc` file:

```
termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@
```

Doing this makes the local scrollbuffer contain the correct data, and on `gnome-terminal`, it's then possible to scroll using the slider on the edge of the window.

You should probably make sure only to use a single tab per terminal, since swapping tabs will obviously mess up the local scrollbuffer.

What is missing is that mouse wheel scroll doesn't work yet: have to use the slider on the edge of the terminal.